# How to retun value from RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database, enterprise-library

Hi I am new to new Azure SQL Server. I am trying to connect SQL server and return some data from there by calling stored procedure over there. I am passing two parameter like username and password and then get user details for valid user from stored procedure.

To connect Azure SQL server I am using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling to make connection from application and using same code mentioned over this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961167.aspx . But here it is using `public Action IssueQueryCommand_action;` to execute any action against connection. In this case, it does not return any result. I want to get DataReader from from ExecuteAction like this mentioned in above link

```
// [A.1] Connect, which proceeds to issue a query command.
                this.connectionRetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(this.EstablishConnection_action);
```

There is option I can use `ExecuteAction<TResult>` as mentioned in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.transientfaulthandling.retrypolicy.executeaction%28v=pandp.60%29.aspx

But don't know how should I call following method by using `RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction Method`

```
public bool IsValidUser(string UserMail, string Password)
    {

        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = this.rsConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandText = ConstantsDAL.SP_IS_VALID_USER;
            sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            return Convert.ToBoolean(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }
```

Can you please help me how to use RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction Method to get scalar value or datareader.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found on MSDN https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca9a2344-d09b-4c64-a88b-fbd42360b876/how-to-retun-value-from-retrypolicyexecuteaction-in?forum=ssdsgetstarted

To repost the MSDN answer, use the following:

`connectionRetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(    ()=>   {       IsValidUser (parameter1,
parameter2);    });`